# grep a list of two strings/words and return only the first result

Tags: linux, grep, xargs

I have a file (biglist.txt) that I need to search for lines that contain two strings and I need the output to only return the first instance of that search. String one (of two) is variable, meaning I have a file that is another long line-separated (hard returned) list of different strings called (queries.txt). The second string will be a constant word (let's call the word "description"). I need to search for lines with variable string + constant string, and only return the first instance of such a search.

I know something like this will work for a list of single strings.

```
cat queries.txt | xargs -I{} grep -m 1 {} biglist.txt > output
```

but I need to add the argument that each of the strings in the queries.txt must also be on a line with the constant word "description". The file "biglist.txt" has multiple lines with each of the strings and the word "description" and I only need to output one of those. Not all of the lines have both the string and the word "description" and often the first line does not have the word "description". This newb appreciates any help.

Comment: queries.txt simplified sample would be 
"GB12345
GB23456
XP_235699H6
etc.x20K" 

but with line breaks (which I'm not sure you can see) and sample text for big list would be 

GB12345,gbkey=Gene;gene=LOC409931


(line break)
 
GB12345;product=protein blah blah

So one line here has the word "product" (which I can interchange with "description") and the other does not. There are multiple lines that have both the variable name and the constant name so I only need to return one of them.

Comment: Consider learning how to use [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Without a better description of the input and expected output this might do the job:

```
grep description biglist.txt | grep -f queries.txt | head -n1
```

Output the first line in biglist.txt that contains description and one of the queries in queries.txt.